# What to do when a question has been answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555463/transform-picture-box-image-to-a-mat-object), and many others like it, seem to get answered as a comment on the question and never actually answered in correct place.

IMO questions should be *answered* as this helps future searchers.

So what should I do? I don't feel right answering the question myself as I don't know this particular question, but the comments lead that it did solve the problem.

Maybe just comment to ask if it could be submitted as an answer? This seems a bit of a faff though..

Comment: I suppose for me, it solved the problem, but i dont know the subject area to know for sure. Does the community wiki part in that answer show that?

Comment: The particular case is an hour old. Perhaps wait for a bit, but if nothing happens, by all means poke the comment author to make it an answer.