# What to do with open questions that have been answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, unanswered-questions

I have been looking through unanswered questions for the Swift tag and a huge number of them have been decided in the comments that it is a bug in the compiler or Xcode. There are also other times where the question gets answered in other ways in the comments.

I feel like these questions clog up the unanswered tab and defeat the purpose of the tab. Is there anything that we can do to clean up these questions or get them off the unanswered tab to make room for genuinely unanswered questions?

Comment: They're still formally unanswered...what's stopping you from incorporating the perceived answer as a community wiki in the question?

Comment: @Makoto, so that is the recommended behavior? Sum up the discussion in the comments in a  community wiki answer?

Comment: @drewag CW sounds like a good strategy to me. If the question is downvoted and answerless ( or no upvoted answers) [it will eventually get deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) but I understand that doesn't address it clogging the unanswered tab right now.

Comment: FYI: There is another question here on MSO with an almost exact dupe title as yours, which links to the question yours has been marked as a dupe of. This should have appeared on the "Questions that may already have your answer" when you wrote this question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280733/what-to-do-when-a-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments

Comment: One thing to consider is that old questions about a compiler bug for a rapidly-changing beta language may not be worth answering; it may be better either to let them age away or vote to close them.